# How can I use \dtlsort with different alphabets?

Tags: sorting, datatool, alphabet, scandinavian-letters

Relevant to [my other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283706/what-could-be-causing-hyperref-and-hanging-to-undo-multicols) regarding Norwegian, I need to sort a number of items alphabetically.

I use this code to collect a list of items defined by `\vocab` into a database called `vocabsort`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{multicol, hanging}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{datatool}                   % for sorting lists

\newcommand{\vocab}[3]{%\parskip=0pt \textbf{#1} (#2) #3~\par%
    \DTLnewrow{vocabsort}%
    \DTLnewdbentry{vocabsort}{norsk}{#1}%
    \DTLnewdbentry{vocabsort}{class}{#2}%
    \DTLnewdbentry{vocabsort}{english}{#3}%
}
\newenvironment{vocabsection}[1]{\noindent \hspace{1em} \textbf{#1} %
    \DTLifdbexists{vocabsort}{\DTLcleardb{vocabsort}}{\DTLnewdb{vocabsort}}%
}% 
{ \dtlsort{norsk}{vocabsort}{\dtlicompare}%
    \displaysorteddb
}
\newcommand{\displaysorteddb}{%
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{hangparas}{0.5em}{1}
            \begin{DTLenvforeach*}{vocabsort}{\norsk=norsk, \class=class, \english=english}
                \textbf{\norsk} (\class) \english~\par
            \end{DTLenvforeach*}
        \end{hangparas}
    \end{multicols}
}

\begin{document}

    \subsection{Foo}

    \begin{vocabsection}{Body Vocab}     
    \vocab{hør}{n.}{hair}
    \vocab{hode}{n.}{head}
    \vocab{øye}{n.}{eyes}
    \vocab{øre}{n.}{ear}
    \vocab{hake}{n.}{chin}
    \vocab{nakke}{n.}{neck}
    \vocab{hånd}{n.}{hand}
    \vocab{finger}{n.}{finger}
    \vocab{arm}{n.}{arm}
    \end{vocabsection}

\end{document}
```

which outputs:

[image]

This order is not correct, as the correct Norwegian alphabetical order is:

> a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z æ ø å

So the words that start with `h` should actually be ordered:

> **hake**
>
> **hode**
>
> **hør**
>
> **hånd**

---

**How do I achieve this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(You'll need version `datatool` v2.25 for this to work. I've only just uploaded it to CTAN, so it make take a day or so to reach the mirrors and TeX distributions.)

The comparison handlers provided by `datatool` (actually defined in `datatool-base.sty`) compare two strings by assigning a numerical code to each element of the strings. The code is assigned as follows:

1. If empty, the code is set to -1.
2. If the character (or macro) is identified as a word break, the code is set to the same as the character code for the space character (32).
3. If the "character" is actually a macro (command), the code is set to 0. As from v2.24, if this macro is identified as the first octet of a UTF-8 character (and the UTF-8 option has been enabled), then the code is instead obtained using `\dtlsetUTFviiicharcode{octets}{register}` (for case-sensitive comparisons) or `\dtlsetUTFviiilccharcode{octets}{register}` (for case-insensitive comparisons).
4. If none of the above apply, the code is set using `\dtlsetcharcode{character}{register}` (for case-sensitive comparisons) or `\dtlsetlccharcode{character}{register}` (for case-insensitive comparisons). These commands were introduced in v2.24. Earlier versions simply set the character code using TeX's backtick method (with `\lccode` for case-insensitive comparisons).

(Note that although these new commands were introduced in v2.24, the more recent v2.25 fixes a bug that affects this answer.)

There are therefore two approaches that depend on the document's input encoding.

## Latin-1

(This should also work with other encodings where each character is viewed as a single TeX token.)

The two commands that are relevant in this case are `\dtlsetcharcode` and `\dtlsetlccharcode`. The default definitions are:

```
\newcommand*{\dtlsetcharcode}[2]{#2=`#1\relax}
\newcommand*{\dtlsetlccharcode}[2]{#2=\lccode`#1\relax}
```

(The first argument is the character and the second is a count register in which to store the character code.) Using this method, the codes for the Norwegian characters are as follows:

```
Å 197
Æ 198
Ø 216
å 229
æ 230
ø 248
```

(For reference `A` -> 65, `Z` -> 90, `a` -> 97, `z` -> 122.) So this puts all the Norwegian characters after `z` in the above order. If you want to change this order, you need to redefine `\dtlsetcharcode` and `\dtlsetlccharcode`. For example, for the Norwegian alphabet:

```
\renewcommand*{\dtlsetcharcode}[2]{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{æ}%
  {%
    #2=123\relax
  }%
  {%
    \ifstrequal{#1}{ø}%
    {%
      #2=124\relax
    }%
    {%
      \ifstrequal{#1}{å}%
      {%
        #2=125\relax
      }%
      {%
        \ifstrequal{#1}{Æ}%
        {%
          #2=91\relax
        }%
        {%
          \ifstrequal{#1}{Ø}%
          {%
            #2=92\relax
          }%
          {%
            \ifstrequal{#1}{Å}%
            {%
              #2=93\relax
            }%
            {%
              #2=`#1\relax
            }%
          }%
        }%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}

\renewcommand*{\dtlsetlccharcode}[2]{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{æ}%
  {%
    #2=123\relax
  }%
  {%
    \ifstrequal{#1}{ø}%
    {%
      #2=124\relax
    }%
    {%
      \ifstrequal{#1}{å}%
      {%
        #2=125\relax
      }%
      {%
        \ifstrequal{#1}{Æ}%
        {%
          #2=123\relax
        }%
        {%
          \ifstrequal{#1}{Ø}%
          {%
            #2=124\relax
          }%
          {%
            \ifstrequal{#1}{Å}%
            {%
              #2=125\relax
            }%
            {%
              #2=\lccode`#1\relax
            }%
          }%
        }%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}
```

These use the `etoolbox` conditional `\ifstrequal` for clarity. There are more efficient ways of doing this using TeX's conditionals, such as `\ifnum`. For example:

```
\renewcommand*{\dtlsetcharcode}[2]{%
  #2=`#1\relax
  \ifnum#2=230\relax
    #2=123\relax
  \else
    \ifnum#2=248\relax
      #2=124\relax
    \else
      \ifnum#2=229\relax
        #2=125\relax
      \else
       \ifnum#2=198\relax
          #2=91\relax
       \else
         \ifnum#2=216\relax
            #2=92\relax
         \else
           \ifnum#2=197\relax
              #2=93\relax
           \fi
         \fi
       \fi
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
}

\renewcommand*{\dtlsetlccharcode}[2]{%
  #2=\lccode`#1\relax
  \ifnum#2=230\relax
    #2=123\relax
  \else
    \ifnum#2=248\relax
      #2=124\relax
    \else
      \ifnum#2=229\relax
        #2=125\relax
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
}
```

These redefinitions can be added to your example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{datatool}

\renewcommand*{\dtlsetcharcode}[2]{%
  #2=`#1\relax
  \ifnum#2=230\relax
    #2=123\relax
  \else
    \ifnum#2=248\relax
      #2=124\relax
    \else
      \ifnum#2=229\relax
        #2=125\relax
      \else
       \ifnum#2=198\relax
          #2=91\relax
       \else
         \ifnum#2=216\relax
            #2=92\relax
         \else
           \ifnum#2=197\relax
              #2=93\relax
           \fi
         \fi
       \fi
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
}

\renewcommand*{\dtlsetlccharcode}[2]{%
  #2=\lccode`#1\relax
  \ifnum#2=230\relax
    #2=123\relax
  \else
    \ifnum#2=248\relax
      #2=124\relax
    \else
      \ifnum#2=229\relax
        #2=125\relax
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
}

\newcommand{\vocab}[3]{%
    \DTLnewrow{vocabsort}%
    \DTLnewdbentry{vocabsort}{norsk}{#1}%
    \DTLnewdbentry{vocabsort}{class}{#2}%
    \DTLnewdbentry{vocabsort}{english}{#3}%
}
\newenvironment{vocabsection}[1]{\noindent \hspace{1em} \textbf{#1} %
    \DTLifdbexists{vocabsort}{\DTLcleardb{vocabsort}}{\DTLnewdb{vocabsort}}%
}% 
{ \dtlsort{norsk}{vocabsort}{\dtlicompare}%
    \displaysorteddb
}
\newcommand{\displaysorteddb}{%
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{hangparas}{0.5em}{1}
            \begin{DTLenvforeach*}{vocabsort}{\norsk=norsk, \class=class, \english=english}
                \textbf{\norsk} (\class) \english~\par
            \end{DTLenvforeach*}
        \end{hangparas}
    \end{multicols}
}

\begin{document}

    \subsection{Foo}

    \begin{vocabsection}{Body Vocab}
    \vocab{hør}{n.}{hair}
    \vocab{hode}{n.}{head}
    \vocab{øye}{n.}{eyes}
    \vocab{øre}{n.}{ear}
    \vocab{hake}{n.}{chin}
    \vocab{nakke}{n.}{neck}
    \vocab{hånd}{n.}{hand}
    \vocab{finger}{n.}{finger}
    \vocab{arm}{n.}{arm}
    \end{vocabsection}

\end{document}\newcommand{\displaysorteddb}{%
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{hangparas}{0.5em}{1}
            \begin{DTLenvforeach*}{vocabsort}{\norsk=norsk, \class=class, \english=english}
                \textbf{\norsk} (\class) \english~\par
            \end{DTLenvforeach*}
        \end{hangparas}
    \end{multicols}
}

\begin{document}

    \subsection{Foo}

    \begin{vocabsection}{Body Vocab}
    \vocab{hør}{n.}{hair}
    \vocab{hode}{n.}{head}
    \vocab{øye}{n.}{eyes}
    \vocab{øre}{n.}{ear}
    \vocab{hake}{n.}{chin}
    \vocab{nakke}{n.}{neck}
    \vocab{hånd}{n.}{hand}
    \vocab{finger}{n.}{finger}
    \vocab{arm}{n.}{arm}
    \end{vocabsection}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: image of document]

which has the desired ordering: hake, hode, hør, hånd.

## UTF-8

UTF-8 support is enabled by loading `inputenc` with the `utf8` option before loading `datatool-base` (which is automatically loaded by `datatool`). You can also enable or disable it later with `\dtlenableUTFviii` or `\dtldisableUTFviii`.

In this case, `\dtlsetUTFviiicharcode` and `\dtlsetUTFviiilccharcode` are used to set the character code where the first argument consists if the two octet tokens that make up the UTF-8 character. The default definitions of these commands are:

```
\newcommand*\dtlsetUTFviiicharcode[2]{\dtlsetdefaultUTFviiicharcode{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand*\dtlsetUTFviiilccharcode[2]{\dtlsetdefaultUTFviiilccharcode{#1}{#2}}
```

These default commands set the code for some common supplemental accented Latin characters to be the same as the code for the unaccented version. (For example, `é` is given the same character code as `e`. So a UTF-8 version of your example document is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{datatool}

\renewcommand*{\dtlsetUTFviiicharcode}[2]{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{Æ}%
  {%
    #2=91\relax
  }%
  {%
    \ifstrequal{#1}{Ø}%
    {%
      #2=92\relax
    }%
    {%
      \ifstrequal{#1}{Å}%
      {%
        #2=93\relax
      }%
      {%
        \ifstrequal{#1}{æ}%
        {%
          #2=123\relax
        }%
        {%
          \ifstrequal{#1}{ø}%
          {%
            #2=124\relax
          }%
          {%
            \ifstrequal{#1}{å}%
            {%
              #2=125\relax
            }%
            {%
              \dtlsetdefaultUTFviiicharcode{#1}{#2}%
            }%
          }%
        }%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}

\renewcommand*{\dtlsetUTFviiilccharcode}[2]{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{Æ}%
  {%
    #2=123\relax
  }%
  {%
    \ifstrequal{#1}{Ø}%
    {%
      #2=124\relax
    }%
    {%
      \ifstrequal{#1}{Å}%
      {%
        #2=125\relax
      }%
      {%
        \ifstrequal{#1}{æ}%
        {%
          #2=123\relax
        }%
        {%
          \ifstrequal{#1}{ø}%
          {%
            #2=124\relax
          }%
          {%
            \ifstrequal{#1}{å}%
            {%
              #2=125\relax
            }%
            {%
              \dtlsetdefaultUTFviiilccharcode{#1}{#2}%
            }%
          }%
        }%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}


\newcommand{\vocab}[3]{%
    \DTLnewrow{vocabsort}%
    \DTLnewdbentry{vocabsort}{norsk}{#1}%
    \DTLnewdbentry{vocabsort}{class}{#2}%
    \DTLnewdbentry{vocabsort}{english}{#3}%
}
\newenvironment{vocabsection}[1]{\noindent \hspace{1em} \textbf{#1} %
    \DTLifdbexists{vocabsort}{\DTLcleardb{vocabsort}}{\DTLnewdb{vocabsort}}%
}% 
{ \dtlsort{norsk}{vocabsort}{\dtlicompare}%
    \displaysorteddb
}
\newcommand{\displaysorteddb}{%
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{hangparas}{0.5em}{1}
            \begin{DTLenvforeach*}{vocabsort}{\norsk=norsk, \class=class, \english=english}
                \textbf{\norsk} (\class) \english~\par
            \end{DTLenvforeach*}
        \end{hangparas}
    \end{multicols}
}

\begin{document}

    \subsection{Foo}

    \begin{vocabsection}{Body Vocab}     
    \vocab{hør}{n.}{hair}
    \vocab{hode}{n.}{head}
    \vocab{øye}{n.}{eyes}
    \vocab{øre}{n.}{ear}
    \vocab{hake}{n.}{chin}
    \vocab{nakke}{n.}{neck}
    \vocab{hånd}{n.}{hand}
    \vocab{finger}{n.}{finger}
    \vocab{arm}{n.}{arm}
    \end{vocabsection}

\end{document}
```

This produces the same result:

[image: image same as before]

Comment: @Azor-Ahai In what way didn't it work? Did it produce an error or unexpected output? What version of `datatool` do you have? The examples I provided won't work for older versions. Are you using LaTeX or XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX?

Comment: I simply cannot get `datatool` to update. I've reinstalled MikTeX both admin and local multiple times, which tells me I have 2.25, I installed it from CTAN to `localtexmf` but the log file still tells me I'm using 2.24

Comment: @Azor-Ahai I'm sorry I can't help with MikTeX (I use TeX Live). Perhaps one of the [miktex questions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=[miktex]update) might provide a solution.

Comment: Ah! I fixed it. Thanks so much, this is much more painless than my previous jury-rigged solutions.

Comment: I just realized I used "himself" in an earlier comment and didn't realize you were a woman. Sorry about that! Your thumbnail avatar looks a bit like a chill dude with a soul patch!

Comment: @Azor-Ahai I've been meaning to change my avatar, perhaps I'd better get round to it! :-)

Answer (score 3):

This problem might be similar to that of sorting index entries. When you want to force a specific sort placement (indirectly, a sort order), you have to provide the sorting algorithm with some help.

In your application, I would supply a regular English alphabet *replacement* or *Norsk English* that will be used to sort entries on. To that end, create an additional field in your database where you replace each `æ` with `za`, each `ø` with `zb` and each `å` with `zc` (say), in order to have them sorted sequentially *after* `z`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{datatool,xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\vocab}{m o m m}{%\parskip=0pt \textbf{#1} (#2) #3~\par%
  \DTLnewrow{vocabsort}%
  \DTLnewdbentry{vocabsort}{norsk}{#1}% Norsk
  \IfNoValueF{#2}{\DTLnewdbentry{vocabsort}{norsksort}{#2}}% Norsk sort
  \DTLnewdbentry{vocabsort}{class}{#3}% Class
  \DTLnewdbentry{vocabsort}{english}{#4}% English
}
\newenvironment{vocabsection}[1]{\noindent \textbf{#1} \par \medskip
  \DTLifdbexists{vocabsort}{\DTLcleardb{vocabsort}}{\DTLnewdb{vocabsort}}%
}% 
{ \dtlsort[norsk]{norsksort}{vocabsort}{\dtlicompare}%
  \displaysorteddb
}
\newcommand{\displaysorteddb}{%
  \begin{DTLenvforeach*}{vocabsort}{\norsk=norsk, \class=class, \english=english}
    \textbf{\norsk} (\class) \english~\par
  \end{DTLenvforeach*}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{vocabsection}{Body Vocab}     
  \vocab{hør}[hzbr]{n.}{hair}  % ø > zb
  \vocab{hode}{n.}{head}
  \vocab{øye}[zbye]{n.}{eyes}  % ø > zb
  \vocab{øre}[zbre]{n.}{ear}   % ø > zb
  \vocab{hake}{n.}{chin}
  \vocab{nakke}{n.}{neck}
  \vocab{hånd}[hzcnd]{n.}{hand}% å > zc
  \vocab{finger}{n.}{finger}
  \vocab{arm}{n.}{arm}
\end{vocabsection}

\end{document}
```

The sort order is supplied as an optional second argument using the interface

```
\vocab{<norsk>}[<norsk sort>]{<class>}{<english>}
```

The addition of `<norsk sort>` into the database is conditional on its existence. The macro

```
\dtlsort[norsk]{norsksort}{vocabsort}{\dtlicompare}
```

uses the field `norsksort` as sorting preference in the database `vocabsort` (using a case `i`nsensitive `compare`), and `norsk` only if `norsksort` is absent (null or `\DTLstringnull`).

As mentioned, this is no different than using the `a@b` suggestion with `\index`; that is, place `b` in the index, but sort it as `a` (see section **2.2 The Basics**/p 4 of the [`makeindex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/makeindex) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/indexing/makeindex/doc/makeindex.pdf)). The typical usage would involve something like `\index{alpha@$\alpha$}`. One could, of course, also change the above `\vocab` interface to take a similar input, if needed.

Comment: Thanks, but this makes me feel dirty. Surely there's a better way? Entering those `\vocab` items is time-consuming enough.

Comment: @Azor-Ahai: It's possible to only have to supply a Norsk sort order when the word has a non-English letter in it. That way you don't have to supply it with every word...

Comment: @Azor-Ahai: See the update that makes the sort order optional.

Comment: FTR: This works with PDFLaTeX, but not La-, Xe-, or LuaLaTeX

Comment: I automated the creation of `norsksort` with this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285823/multi-substring-replace