# Multi-substring replace

Tags: characters, xstring, alphabet, scandinavian-letters

I'm attempting to automate Werner's answer to my question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/284527/how-can-i-use-dtlsort-with-different-alphabets).

---

In short, in order to sort the Norwegian letters `Æ Ø Å` (they come at the end of the regular Latin alphabet) correctly `dtlsort` needs some help. This means replacing `æ` with `za`, `ø` with `zb`, etc.

I tried doing this with `xstring`'s `\StrSubstitute` command, but it can only replace one string at a time, and doesn't seem to like being nested.

One single pass works in `PDFLaTeX`.

---

This MWE should output `zbzazc`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{datatool,xparse}
\usepackage{xstring}

\NewDocumentCommand{\norskletterssub}{m}{%
    \def\strA{\StrSubstitute{#1}{æ}{za}}
    \def\strB{\StrSubstitute{\strA}{ø}{zb}}
    \def\strC{\StrSubstitute{\strB}{å}{zc}}
    \strC
    }

\begin{document}

    \norskletterssub{øæå}

\end{document}
```

---

I need to run multiple passes because there's obviously no guarantee there's only one of each letter.

Additionally, there aren't any capital letters that need to be checked for.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I fully endorse using an `expl3` based method, here's how you can do the same with `xstring`.

1. You should use the trailing optional argument, not doing `\def\strA{\StrSubstitute{...}{...}{...}}`
2. You have to care about not doing unwanted expansion: with the `utf8` option, the non ASCII characters are essentially macros, hence `\noexpandarg` is in order.

Here's the code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{datatool,xparse}
\usepackage{xstring}

\NewDocumentCommand{\norskletterssub}{m}{%
  \saveexpandmode\noexpandarg
  \def\tempstring{#1}%
  \xStrSubstitute{\tempstring}{æ}{za}[\tempstring]%
  \xStrSubstitute{\tempstring}{ø}{zb}[\tempstring]%
  \xStrSubstitute{\tempstring}{å}{zc}[\tempstring]%
  \tempstring
  \restoreexpandmode
}
\newcommand*{\xStrSubstitute}{%
  \expandafter\StrSubstitute\expandafter
}

\begin{document}

\norskletterssub{øæå}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If your aim is to do the substitution for a check such as with `\IfStrEq`, you can do

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\IfNorskStrEq}{mmmm}{%
  \saveexpandmode\noexpandarg
  \def\tempstring{#1}%
  \xStrSubstitute{\tempstring}{æ}{za}[\tempstring]%
  \xStrSubstitute{\tempstring}{ø}{zb}[\tempstring]%
  \xStrSubstitute{\tempstring}{å}{zc}[\tempstring]%
  \restoreexpandmode
  \IfStrEq{\tempstring}{#2}{#3}{#4}%
}
\newcommand*{\xStrSubstitute}{%
  \expandafter\StrSubstitute\expandafter
}
```

Now something like

```
\IfNorskStrEq{våkne}}{vzckne}{true}{false}
```

should evaluate to true.

Comment: While this works for my question as asked, it has problems with my overarching question, which is how sort Norwegian words. For some reason, this is fails with `\dtlsort`. Do you have any idea why? (I thought I'd ask, in case it's an encoding issue I'm not familiar with, before posting a third question about my same problem.)

Comment: @Azor-Ahai Not without seeing the real thing, I'm afraid.

Comment: Would it help to know `\IfStrEq{\norskletterssub{våkne}}{vzckne}{true}{false}` evaluates to false?

Comment: @Azor-Ahai Yes, of course it evaluates to false. You have to do `\norskletterssub{våkne}\IfStrEq{\tempstring}{vzckne}{true}{false}`; but remove the last call of `\tempstring` in the definition of `\norskletterssub`.

Comment: Ah, I assumed \tempstring was local to `\norskletterssub`. But doesn't the command `\tempstring` within the command definition output the new string, like in your example?

Comment: @Azor-Ahai I removed the final call to `\tempstring` that in the `\norskletterssub` was used to print the changed string, see the edit to the answer.

Comment: Sorry, my phone cut off your comment at the end of `\IfStrEq`, so I assumed that was the end of it.

Comment: Sorry, still not a lot of luck getting this to work in context. I've posted a new question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287195/sorting-macro-generated-text

Answer (score 7):

The programming layer `expl3` of the upcoming LaTeX3 offers a lot of handy functions for such tasks.  In `expl3` the underscore `_` character can be used in macro names.  We first allocate a new token list variable

```
\tl_new:N \l_azor_string_tl
```

Then we define a code level function, which sets the token list variable to the input string and then replaces the desired substrings.

```
\cs_new_protected:Npn \azor_replace_norsk:n #1
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_azor_string_tl { #1 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_azor_string_tl { æ } { za }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_azor_string_tl { ø } { zb }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_azor_string_tl { å } { zc }
  \tl_use:N \l_azor_string_tl
 }
```

In the end we defined a document level function (i.e. the one which is to be used by you in when typing the document), which simply calls the code level function with the appropriate argument.

```
\NewDocumentCommand \norskletterssub { m }
 {
  \azor_replace_norsk:n { #1 }
 }
```

(Unfortunately the whole thing is not expandable, i.e. when doing `\edef\temp{\norskletterssub{øæå}}` the macro `\temp` will *not* contain `zbzazc`, but still `\norskletterssub {øæå}`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l_azor_string_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \azor_replace_norsk:n #1
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_azor_string_tl { #1 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_azor_string_tl { æ } { za }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_azor_string_tl { ø } { zb }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_azor_string_tl { å } { zc }
  \tl_use:N \l_azor_string_tl
 }

\NewDocumentCommand \norskletterssub { m }
 {
  \azor_replace_norsk:n { #1 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

øæå \norskletterssub{øæå}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Can you maybe explain your code a little? I haven't used expl3 before.

Comment: @Azor-Ahai See updated answer.