# Expand arguments to DeclareFieldFormat to replace words in biblatex field

Tags: biblatex

I'm trying to use biblatex to automatically replace words in the booktitle field with their abbreviations (e.g. Proceedings to Proc., Symposium to Symp. etc.).  My approach has been to use the `\DeclareFieldFormat` macro (with a substitution macro courtesy of [Multi-substring replace](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285823/multi-substring-replace)):

```
\newcommand{\shorten}[1]{%
    \saveexpandmode\noexpandarg
    \def\x{#1}%
    \xStrSubstitute{\x}{Proceedings}{Proc.}[\x]%
    \x%
    \message{\x}
    \restoreexpandmode
}
\newcommand*{\xStrSubstitute}{%
    \expandafter\StrSubstitute\expandafter
}

\DeclareFieldFormat[inproceedings]{booktitle}{\shorten{#1}}
```

The problem is that when the `DeclareFieldFormat` is run, the argument hasn't yet been expanded to the actual data value, so the argument passed to `shorten` is actually: `\printfield [titlecase]{booktitle}\setunit {\addperiod  }\printfield [titlecase]{booksubtitle}` (printed by the `message` call).

Any ideas on how to get the actual booktitle out of biblatex so I can run my macro on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply the format directly. The `booktitle` macro looks as follows

```
\newbibmacro*{booktitle}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{booktitle}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{booksubtitle}}
  }
    {}
    {\printtext[booktitle]{%
       \printfield[titlecase]{booktitle}%
       \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
       \printfield[titlecase]{booksubtitle}}%
     \newunit}%
  \printfield{booktitleaddon}}
```

So the `booktitle` command is actually in the outer `\printtext` and not directly in the `\printfield`.

Define a new format and use that

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{shortenbooktitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inproceedings]{shortenbooktitle}{\shorten{#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{booktitle}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{booktitle}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{booksubtitle}}
  }
    {}
    {\printtext[booktitle]{%
       \printfield[shortenbooktitle]{booktitle}%
       \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
       \printfield[shortenbooktitle]{booksubtitle}}%
     \newunit}%
  \printfield{booktitleaddon}}
```

---

You can also use Biber to do the replacement and don't have to worry about anything else.

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \pertype{inproceedings}
      \step[fieldsource=booktitle,
              match=\regexp{Proceedings},
              replace=\regexp{Proc.}]
      \step[fieldsource=booktitle,
              match=\regexp{Symposium},
              replace=\regexp{Symp.}]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Where did you find the code of the `booktitle` macro?  I also want to do this to the `journal` field in the `article` type.

Comment: @Joe You can find most of the code in `biblatex.def` and `standard.bbx`. The `booktitle` and `journal` macros are both in `biblatex.def`. Let me emphasise again that I would use Biber over string manipulation via `\DeclareFieldFormat`.

Comment: Thanks again.  Unfortunately, I'm forced to use bibtex due to co-author requirements, but I'll keep it in mind for the future.